# Faster way to Restore Postgresql Dump Taken by Pg_dumpall?

Tags: postgresql, backup, restore

I have a database server which consists multiple databases and the size is nearly 1 TB. The problem is, it takes very long (hours) to restore from the dump.

Normally i restore my database via this command below:

```
psql -p 1590 < mydump.dump
```

Is there any way that i can make this faster? I tried pg_restore but it didn't work:

```
pg_restore -j 5 -p 1590 -f mydump.dump
```

Comment: If you want to use `pg_restore` you need to make a dump in custom format. But that can't be done with `pg_dumpall`, only `pg_dump`

Comment: I have like 15 databases inside the server. Is there a practical way to take dumps of each database + global items from pg_dumpall?

Comment: A little shell script can do that. I am pretty sure there are loads of examples out there

Comment: I couldn't find one. Can you share one if you find any? Thanks.

Comment: See e.g. [here](https://www.depesz.com/2019/12/10/how-to-effectively-dump-postgresql-databases/) or [here](https://gist.github.com/powellc/4162155)